# GeoKettle, adding Source Values into Value Mapper

Tags: geokettle

I'm testing GeoKettle to see if it can help me transfer shapefiles from one schema to another.  I'm trying to use the value mapper but am finding that all Source Values and corresponding Target Values have to be entered manually - is there a way to make this process more efficient.

- I know that in FME you can scan a feature to automatically read in
  source values - this doesn't seem to be possible in GeoKettle.
- I also understand that FME allows you to somehow attach an external
  lookup table - I can't see a way to do this in GeoKettle.
- I have tried copying values from a spreadsheet or text document but
  they do not paste into the ValueMapper dialog in the correct way.